# How do I change certain rows in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

with this code work good, thanks everyone, I should practice in this great world of android platform good night.

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30ffffff, 0x30808080 };
        Galeria city = items.get(position);    
        String color =city.getEquipo().toString();   
        if(convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
          }

            ImageView image3 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgCel);
            //image3.setImageBitmap(city.getPhoto());

            ImageView image2 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgRojo);

        if (position<=5){
            image3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{

            image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? Why isn't `setBackground[XY]` approach working for you? Did you try to change the color? Share your code, and maybe the renderer layout too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what kind of `Adapter` you used, there is a `getView([...])` method you should override in order to accomplish your task. With the `position` parameter, you can know the row number you are going to decorate. So you can use

```
if(position<3) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: With that code change everything, only I need especific rows of the listview.

Comment: You sure? even with the checking of the "position" parameter?

Comment: hello, check my code above.